# DataGrid selection not extractable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I'm using a DataGrid and I want to dispatch the selection to my redux store.

```
return (
        <div style={{ height: '470px', width: '100%' }}>
            <p>*{statement.multiplier}</p>
            <DataGrid
                rows={rows}
                columns={columns}
                checkboxSelection
                disableSelectionOnClick
                onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
                    const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
                    const selectedRows = rows.filter((row) =>
                      selectedIDs.has(row.id),
                    );
                    setSelectedRows(selectedRows);
                    dispatch(setSelection(selectedRows))
                }}
            />
            <br/>
        </div>
    );
```

But for some reason, selectedRows never gets filled. I find this especially strange since I literally copy/pasted this from one of my earlier projects.

Does anyone know why this line:

```
const selectedRows = rows.filter((row) =>
                  selectedIDs.has(row.id),
                );
```

Comes up empty every time?